# Show that $2f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(-\zeta)}{\zeta^{2}} d\zeta,$ whenever $0<r<1.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. Show that
$$2f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(-\zeta)}{\zeta^{2}} d\zeta,$$
whenever $0<r<1.$

So far my understanding of this problem is that I need to prove that we have $f(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(-z)}{2}$ for $z$ satisfying $|z|<1$, since the rest is an application of Cauchy's Integral Formula. I noted that the result is true if an only if we have $f(z)=-f(-z)$, for all $z$ satisfying the said condition. Here is where I am stuck so far. Could you please provide a small hint to point me in the right direction, please provide no complete solution, only small hints.

Comment: You meant $\int_{|\zeta|=r}$ and $f(-\zeta)$ appears with a change of variable in Cauchy's integral formula. For the intuition in those contour integral on a circle you are allowed to assume $f$ is given by a power series.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I fixed the mistake. And thank you for the suggestion as well.

Comment: With Taylor expansion
$$f(\zeta)-f(-\zeta)=\left(f(0)+f'(0)\zeta+\dfrac12f''(0)\zeta^2+\cdots\right)-\left(f(0)-f'(0)\zeta+\dfrac12f''(0)\zeta^2+\cdots\right)=\left(2f'(0)\zeta+2\dfrac16f'''(0)\zeta^3+\cdots\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

By extension Cauchy's Integral Formula ,we have

$$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r} \frac{f(\zeta)}{{(\zeta-z_0)}^{n+1}} d\zeta,$$

provided $f(\zeta) is \ analytic\ in\ |\zeta|\ = \ r$

So,

$$2f'(0)=\frac{2*1!}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{2}} d\zeta$$
$$\quad =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r} \frac{f(\zeta)-(-\zeta)}{\zeta^{2}} d\zeta \quad (given)$$

And ,Since $f(\zeta)$  is  analytic in $|\zeta| = r $  ,
thus it is continuous and differentiable in that region,

So ,$2f(\zeta)$ and  $f(\zeta) - f(-\zeta)$ are two continuous and differentiable functions with same antiderivatives

So , Two functions must be equal.

Hence,$$2f(\zeta) = f(\zeta) - f(-\zeta)$$
$$f(\zeta) =  - f(-\zeta)$$

Comment: Hope, It worked . :)

Comment: " with same antiderivatives for all r" doesn't make sense. try $n=1,z_0= 0$ then the change of variable $\zeta = -\eta$ in your 1st formula.